# App problems and logs not helping me find error

Tags: java, android

I have a card game I'm creating, I can buy one card (same card) 12 times and there are 16 of these cards, then whenever I touch the screen it anywhere it breaks.

- I have added tons of Logs for debugging; But it breaks at an `if` statement which has never happen to me before.

**Note:** this `if` statement is an `if` with 5 `else if` all with logs in the inner brackets like  "bug paused 4.1", but none are reached. making believed it's breaking here but I don't know why.

```
if(card!= null) {
    Log.i("c", "bug paused 4 "+ buy + "  " + prev + "  " + card.name );
}
//-----------------------------play card------------------------------
if (card != null && event.x > 315 && event.x < 405 && event.y > 170 && event.y < 260
     && buy == false) {
     Log.i("c", " bug paused 4.1");
}
else if {
    //do code but log here
}
    // etc....
else {}
```

```
// my logs
18:55:25.259    29927   #29927  INFO    c    bug paused
18:55:25.259    29927   #29927  INFO    c    bug paused 2
18:55:25.259    29927   #29927  INFO    c    bug paused 3
18:55:25.259    29927   #29927  INFO    c    bug paused 4 true  Running  queen
```

This is my code and the last 4 log that are received and the app breaks.

Comment: Have you tried using an interactive debugger and its ability to set breakpoints, single-step code, and view variables and fields?

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: You'll need to provide a more complete look at the code and the exact stack trace. There's not enough here to work with.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your actual issue is. Does it crash, a method has a wrong implementation, or ??

Comment: What are all the x and y coordinates for? Have you taken into account the fact that they might differ based on different screen sizes and DPIs?